# Realtime D3 bubble chart (circle pack)

Tags: javascript, d3.js, transition, circle-pack

I'm trying to create a **realtime bubble chart in d3.js** The chart itself is simple as the data displayed is a non-nested array. It's just bubbles of different size.

The initial bubble chart with initial data fetched from an MVC controller via ajax is created like this:

```
var canvas = d3.select("#dynD3")
    .append("svg")
    .attr("width", 800)
    .attr("height", 500)
    .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(50, 50)");

var pack = d3.layout.pack()
    .size([800, 450])
    .padding(10);

d3.json("/Nice/d3_getCoolBubble", function (data) {

  var nodes = pack.nodes(data);
  console.log(data);

  var node = canvas.selectAll(".node")
    .data(nodes)
    .enter()
    .append("g")
    .attr("class", "node")
    .attr("transform", function (d) {
        return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")";
    });

  node.append("circle")
    .attr("class", function (d) { return d.children ? "noupdate" : "update" })
    .attr("id", function (d) { return d.name; })
    .attr("r", function (d) { return d.r })
    .attr("fill", function (d) { return d.children ? "#fff" : "steelblue" })
    .attr("stroke", function (d) { return d.children ? "#fff" : "#000" })
    .attr("stroke-width", "2");

  node.append("text")
    .text(function (d) { return d.children ? "" : d.name; });
```

Appended to the creation of the initial bubbles is a call to the

```
        tick()
```

function. This function should take care of fetching new data from the MVC controller and then performing the transitions. After the transitions have finished, the method calls itself again:

```
    function tick() {

        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            async: false,
            url: "/Nice/d3_getCoolBubble",
            data: {},
            success: function (result) {

                console.log(result);

                var update = canvas.selectAll(".update");

                update.transition()
                    .duration(5000)
                    .attr("transform", function (d) {
                        return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")";
                    })
                    .each("end", tick);
            }
        });
    };
});
```

I'd be glad if someone had a good link, example or hint on how to perform the update. I guess it must be something like

- fetch new data
- calculate new model
- add / remove nodes that are new / no longer in the newly fetched data
- start transitions for all existing nodes

Thanks for any hints!

Comment: As a suggestion, the `attr()` method can accept an object of key/value pairs, instead of calling it for each attribute. Also, why do you have `async: false`?

Comment: async: false is not needed, you're right. You mean melt the chained attr() into one?

Comment: Yeah, IMO it is just cleaner. `$().attr({ key: value, foo: bar})`

Comment: The steps you list at the end sound ok to me.

Comment: Hi Lars, yes, the steps make sense to me, too. But I feel like having to talk in latin when all I could was read it ..

Comment: Have you seen [this tutorial](http://mbostock.github.io/d3/tutorial/bar-2.html)?

Comment: Thanks for the link, Lars! I'll work that through.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IE decided to AUTO-CACHE the standard "d3.json()" request. So I switched for an explicit jQuery ajax request with 'cache: false'. In its basic form, the update now works, though the code might still exhibit some of my legastheny towards d3.

I thought I'd use it to visualize the number of users watching a tv channel in our intranet tv site but I think I'll switch to a line chart.. nevertheless, here's the code:

```
function dynamicBubbles() {

// call redraw every 5 sec
setInterval(function() {
    redraw();
}, 5000);

var width = 960;
var height = 500;

// construct SVG container
var chart = d3.select("#dynD3").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height)
    .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(50, 50)");

// define our pack
var pack = d3.layout.pack()
    .size([width, height - 50])
    .padding(10);

function redraw() {

// get data from MVC controller
return $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    async: true,
    cache: false,
    url: "/Nice/d3_getCoolBubble",
    data: { },
    success: function (data) {

        // asign new data to existing layout
        var node = chart.selectAll(".node")
            .data(pack.nodes(data), function (d) { return d.name });

        // access brand new data
        node.enter().append("g")
                .classed("node", true)
                .attr("transform", function (d) { return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")"; })
            .append("circle")
                .attr("fill", function (d) { return d.children ? "#fff" : "steelblue" })
                .attr("stroke", function (d) { return d.children ? "#fff" : "#ADADAD" })
                .attr("stroke-width", "1")
                .transition()
                .attr("r", function (d) { return d.r });

        node.transition()
            .duration(2000)
            .attr("transform", function (d) { return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")"; });


        node.select("circle")
            .transition()
            .duration(2000)
            .attr("r", function (d) { return d.r; })

        node.append("text")
            .text(function (d) { return d.name; });

    }
});
```

Comment: It's called dyslexia in English, in german it's "Legasthenie" (which, opposed to what i thought, is no english word)